# How to disable form validation for undisplayed fields in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my view I have form and in it two fieldsets: modelA and modelB input fields. Some of modelA and modelB fields are required so there is some validation mechanism for this (ValidationMessageFor). I wana show either modelA fieldset or modelB fieldset depending on radio-button for instance (now I do this within jQuery and css display property). I need to disable validation for fields which are in the hidden block. I should not use only css for show/hide functionality?

For example:

Models:

```
public class ModelA
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IC { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="modelA-block">
        // inputs and validation for modelA
    </div>

    <div id="modelB-block">
        // inputs and validation for modelB
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script>
    $(function () {    
        $("#myRadioButton").change(function (arg) {
            var type= $(this).val();
            if (type== 1) {
                $("#modelA-block").css("display", "block");
                $("#modelB-block").css("display", "none");
            }
            if (type== 2) {
                $("#modelA-block").css("display", "none");
                $("#modelB-block").css("display", "block");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Create 1 view model containing the proprieties, including one to bind the radio button to, and apply a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar attribute to the properties.

Comment: It's good but I think I cant use it because I use something like composite model (see below) so I can't see radio property from sub-models.

Comment: I don't mean a model containing other models. I mean a view model containing all the properties. In the example you have shown in would 5 properties - `FirstMidName`, `LastName`, `Position`, `Name` and `IC` plus an additional property for the radiobuttons to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

Create a composite model:

```
public class CompositeModel
{
    public ModelA ModelA {get; set;}
    public ModelB ModelB {get; set;}
}
```

Your view:

```
@model CompositeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="modelA-block">
        // inputs and validation for modelA
        Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelA.FirstMidName)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> <!-- moved inside of a block -->
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="modelB-block">
        // inputs and validation for modelB
        Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ModelB.FirstMidName)

        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> <!-- moved inside of a block -->
    </div>
}

// put your javascript here, create radio button outside form tag
```

In controller create two actions accepting ModelA and ModelB:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName([Bind(Prefix="ModelA")]ModelA model)
{
    //...
}
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName([Bind(Prefix="ModelB")]ModelB model)
{
    //...
}
```

But I would really move away from traditional validation to something like [that](http://timgthomas.com/2013/09/simplify-client-side-validation-by-adding-a-server/).

Comment: It's good approach. I really use something like composite model but I have many other fileds in it (address, contacts etc.) which are common for both of models (ModelA and ModelB). So I think I need it keep in one form.

Comment: What makes you think that? Why do you need to keep them in one form?

Comment: Because I have one composite model for "Conact" and it could be Company or Person and for both there are many other common properties like Address, Email list, Phone list etc. But I thik your approach is good. So I accespt this answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted. It simply does not work! And the reason is that the first textbox generates `name="ModelA.FirstMidName"` but the POST method accepts a parameter of type `ModelA`. Typeof `ModelA` does not have a complex property named `ModelA` which in turn contains a property named `FirstMidName`. Binding fails and the model will always be `null`. (ditto for the other form and associated POST method)

Comment: You could make binding work by adding the `[Bind(Prefix="ModelA")]` but this is a poor solution to a bad design.

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have another solution? Why not post it here? I'll +1 you

Comment: @RomanPushkin, If you edit your answer to include the `[Bind]` attribute - e.g. `public ActionResult YourActionName([Bind(Prefix="ModelA")]ModelA model)` then it will work so I will remove my downvote. I'll add my own answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments that one model is `Company` and the other `Person`, then I suggest you UI is wrong and a better approach would be to initially render the radio buttons only and use jquery to handle the buttons `.click()` event to load a partial view containing either a company form or a person form for editing (it would help if your question stated the actual code rather than some psuedo code).

However if you do want this approach, you should use a view model containing the proeprties you want to edit in conjunction with a `[RequiredIf]` attribute. You can download the [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) nuget package or write your own (there are plenty of examples on SO and [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) gives a good explanation of creating validation attributes with client side validation)

View models

```
public enum ContactType
{
  Person,
  Company
}
public class ContactVM
{
  public ContactType Type { get; set; }
  // Common properties such as for the address
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter ..")]
  public string Street { get; set; }
  ....
  // Specify properties for Person
  [Display(Name = "Last name")]
  [RequiredIf("Type", "Person", ErrorMessage="Please enter your last name")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  ....
  // Specify properties for Company
  [Display(Name = "Company name")]
  [RequiredIf("Type", "Company", ErrorMessage="Please enter your company name")]
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

View

```
@model yourAssembly.ContactVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, ContactType.Person, new { id = "Person" })
  <label for="Person">Person</label>
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Type, ContactType.Company, new { id = "Company" })
  <label for="Company">Company</label>
  <div id="person-properties">
      // Controls specific to Person
      ....
  </div>
  <div id="common-properties">
      // Controls specific to Company
      ....
  </div>
  // Common controls
  ....
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(ContactVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsVald)
  {
    return View();
  }
  ContactType type = model.Type;
  if (type == ContactType.Person)
  {
    // Initialize a new instance of Person and map its properties from the view model, save and redirect
  }
  else
  {
    // Initialize a new instance of Company and map its properties from the view model, save and redirect
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@RomanPushkin, you wouldn't need the `Bind` attribute if you place your two forms in two partial views like this:

`_ModelAForm.cshtml` partial:

```
@model ModelA

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostA", "Composite"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstMidName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstMidName)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

`_ModelBForm.cshtml` partial:

```
@model ModelB

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostB", "Composite"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@model CompositeModel

<div id="first-form-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_ModelAForm", Model.ModelA)
</div>

<div id="second-form-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_ModelBForm", Model.ModelB)
</div>
```

And the actions:

```
public ActionResult PostA(ModelA modelA)
{
    //..
}

public ActionResult PostB(ModelB modelB)
{
    //..
}
```